# Excel 2013: table generated by connections switch original table rows

Tags: mysql, excel, excel-formula

Hi I have a table that is simply a copy of another table on another sheet on my workbook.
The second table is generated using

**DATA -> Existing Connections->** and then I select the Table tab.

Usually this work really well but in some cases (not always) the new table has the rows in a different order from the original one. How is it possible to avoid this?